# LevelDB vs. std::map

Tags: c++, stdmap, boost-serialization, leveldb

In our application we use `std::map` to store (key, value) data and use serialization to store that data on disk. With this approach we are finding that the disk I/O is performance bottleneck and finding values using key is not very fast.

I have come across LevelDB and thinking of using it. But I have some questions.

1. LevelDB's documentation says its made for (string, string) key value pair. Does it mean that I can not use for custom key value pairs?
2. It seems the difference between `std::map` and LevelDB is that LevelDB is persistent and `std::map` works in memory. So does it mean the disk I/O bottleneck will be more problematic for levelDB.

More specifically can anybody please explain if LevelDB could be better choice than `std::map`?

PS: I tried using `hash_map`s but it appears to be slower than `std::map`

Comment: How much data are you storing in the std::map?

Comment: Do you need the ordering provided by `std::map`? If not, try `std::unordered_map`.

Comment: if hash_maps are slower, you should look into (a) loadfactor (b) hash function tuning; However, since we don't know anything about usage pattern (volumes, frequencies, read/write balance) all I can do is suggest you profile profile profile

Comment: Fortunately I read this question backwards and saw "PS: I tried using hash_maps but it appears to be slower than std::map" before anything else. So I can just leave the comment: "what? huh? in every case? for all input? for all usage? for all data? make some sense please! profile" Pet hate: misunderstanding of container behaviour

Comment: I did try std::unordered_map but it can not beat std::map performance. Also tuning of hash_map did no help much. I am looking at around a million entries.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

LevelDB just does something else than std::map.

Are you really saying you want (high performance) persistence for std::map?

- look at std::map with a custom allocator. Allocate the entries from a memory mapped region and use fsync to to ensure the information hits the disk at strategic moments in time.

  - [mmap](http://linux.die.net/man/2/mmap)
  - [boost iostreams memory mapped files](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/iostreams/doc/classes/mapped_file.html)
- perhaps combine that with EASTL (which boasts a faster std::map and thrives with custom allocators - in fact they have no default allocator)

  - [EASTL](https://github.com/paulhodge/EASTL)
- look at tuning your hash_map (std::unorderded_map); if hash_maps are slower, you should look into (a) loadfactor (b) hash function tuning

  - [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb982704.aspx)
- last but not least: evaluate the use of Boost Serialization for binary serialization of your map (whatever implementation you picked). In my experience Boost Serialization performance is top of the bill.

  - [Boost serialization](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/serialization/doc/tutorial.html#stl)

Comment: Thanks. About option 1 & 2 need to look in. About 3rd option I tried tunning hash_map but of not much gain. I am using binary serialization. My question is whether LevelDB performance is better than combination of std::map+boost::serialization for a million entries?

Comment: After reading the other comments, I'm pretty certain that only using a DB proper (look _also_ at keyvalue stores such as couchdb, memcache) or memory mapping will lead to improvements. What you essentially need to achieve is _on disk indexed data_ so there is no need to read verything before accessing

Comment: how is this marked as the correct answer if it does not answer the question?

Answer (score 2):

What you're doing now is this:

Say you have 1000000 records in a file. You read the *whole* file into std::map, this takes about ~1000000 operations. You use find/insert to locate and/or insert an element, this takes logarithmic time (about 20 comparisons). And now you save the whole file again, transferring all these 1000000 records back to the file.

The problem is that you benefit absolutely nothing from using std::map. std::map gives you fast search times (logarithmic), but initializing and serializing the whole map per each lookup nullifies it's benefits.

What you need is either redesign you program so you will load the map once at the startup and serialize it once at the termination. Or, perhaps if you need the database semantics, go for a real database implementation. I suggest using SQLite, although LevelDB might be just as good for you.

Comment: Yes, you are right. This is exactly what is happening in our application. And disk I/O nullifies the benefit of std::map performance. We tried using real database semantics and that's bit slow. My question is whether LevelDB performance is better than combination of std::map+boost::serialization for say a million entries?

Comment: @PavanTotala "using real database semantics and that's bit slow" I don't believe you, besides if you tried why do you ask about LevelDB? Yes it will be asymptotically faster, because it won't read the whole file into the memory. Instead it searches within the file with O(log N) reads.

Comment: @ybungalobill- I think there is a difference between real database and LevelDB semantics. So my question was if LevelDB has any advantage over std::map.  Also, when I said real databse seems slow,because it was perceived that searching something on disk is slower than seraching soemthing in memory. You might be correct that  real dabase could be faster.